# Automatic conversion to JSON when using ProducerTemplate

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to send JMS messages containing Java POJOs to ActiveMQ and all messages should be converted to JSON documents. So I need mechanism that will convert POJO to JSON and will send created document as text message to ActiveMQ. I would like to use `ProducerTemplate#send(...)` method without need to define routes. I am using routes on the server, but in my opinion doing so on the client side is an overkill.

This is xml config:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate" />
    <camel:dataFormats>
        <camel:json id="json" library="Jackson" />
    </camel:dataFormats>        
</camel:camelContext>
```

and java code:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "jms:queue:test?jmsMessageType=Text")
private ProducerTemplate camelTemplate;

@Test
public void send() {
    Address address = new Adress("Eric Mouller", "ForstenriederAlle 99", 81476);
    camelTemplate.sendBody(address);
}
```

The current implementation calls `toString()` on `Adress`, but I would like to automatically convert it to JSON, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you are trying to take a java object and convert it into a json string.  So something like Gson would do wonders for you.

Gson gson = new Gson();

String address = gson.toJson(address);

Reference:
https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html

Comment: I would need to convert manually POJOS to JSON before calling ProducerTemplate#send(...). But I would like to register kind of converter on ProducerTemplate, so that every message send over ProducerTemplate will get converted to json.

Comment: Then I would adjust your producer template to send to a direct endpoint and do a marshal and send with a camel route.

Comment: Yes - I do doing it right now, but I wanted to make sure that there is no simpler way... especially on the client side, where I am not using routes - client only sends and receives messages, it's a web application.

Comment: Ok if this is client side its worth noting that the producerTemplate component is a camel library.  If you are just trying to serialize and use activemq, then you can either use a generic jms library or a Resource Adapter to not rely on the camel libraries. <http://activemq.apache.org/resource-adapter.html>

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-8723
Seems it will be fixed in 2.18.0 by adding sendBodyAs to the producerTemplateAPI